# Guidance on reading multiple integers from file, converting them to binary, then printing them to screen?

Tags: c, binary, integer

So I know that's a long title, but I'll try break it down a bit.

I'm trying to create a C program, that will read in an undetermined number of integers from .txt file (under the assumption that the file ONLY contains integers, and each integer is separated by a new line), before then converting each one to binary form, and then exporting it to the screen.

I'm trying to create the program step-by-step, and so far I have managed to create a program which converts to binary, but only from a single user inputted integer (see the code below).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

long int integerInput,quotient;

int binaryNumber[100],i=1,j;


printf("Enter any integer: ");

scanf("%ld",&integerInput);


quotient = integerInput;


while(quotient!=0){

     binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;

     quotient = quotient / 2;

}


printf("Equivalent binary value of integer %d: ",integerInput);

for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)

     printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);


return 0;

}
```

I'm really not sure how to effectively read in the numbers and convert them one by one. I have tried a for loop like below, on a test file which contains 10 different integers (I have declared this file and opened it using the neccessary File I/O).

I tried editing the above code using a for loop, but this doesn't seem to help - it just generates random sequences.

```
for(k=0;k<10;k++)
{
    fscanf(test, "%d", &decimalNumber);
.... // rest of above code is inserted here, minus the scanf and prompts for user to enter a number
return 0;

}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: what is the result that you are getting after fscanf ? try to add a printf after scanf to show the value that you read. and verify the structure of your file.

Comment: Posting the entire problematic `main` instead of describing it would help avoid a long sequence of "did you do this" and "did you do that".

Comment: The code you posted works fine. Instead of describing the code that _doesn't_ work post it.

Comment: The `while` loop should be a `do...while` loop, otherwise the value `0` will not be converted.

Comment: `binaryNumber` array should be zero initialized, so you can easily display also leading zeros if you wish to pad to a specific width, which is common for binary representation. Also, the first element is wasted because index starts from `i=1`. Because `i` and `j` are of signed type, start indexing from 0 and allow equality to 0 in the termination condition of the descending `for` loop. And show the full code that does *not* work!

Answer (score 0):

some recommendations:

1. use `int64_t` from `#include<stdint.h>` instead of `long int`.
2. check for errors, is `scanf` succeeded or not:

   ```
   if (scanf("%ld", &integerInput) != 1){
       printf("incorrect input.\n");
       return 1; // error
   }
   ```
3. you can use OS-pipe/Redirecting standard input or files:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)
   so you can use `scanf` for both user input(stdin) and file input(os pipe).
   this simpilies you code.

so the rest is simple:
use loop then inside loop: read input with `scanf` then convert to binary then `printf`:

4. you can use `itoa` from `#include<stdlib.h>` to Converts an integer to a string:

   ```
   int32_t n = 1234567890;
   char buf[65];
   itoa(n, buf, 2);
   printf("%s\n", buf);  // 1001001100101100000001011010010
   ```

and put together,
working sample code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(){
    int32_t n = 1234567890;
    char buf[65];
    while (1){
        if (scanf("%ld", &n) != 1){
            //printf("incorrect input\n"); // or EOF
            return 1; // error or EOF
        }
        itoa(n, buf, 2);
        printf("%s\n", buf);  // 1001001100101100000001011010010 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And call it like:   file1 < file2.txt

or you may use `fscanf` if you want to.
i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to loop through your input file would be:

```
while( fscanf( fp, "%ld", &inputInteger ) == 1 )
{
  // convert and display inputInteger
}
```

where `fp` is your input stream.  `*scanf` returns the number of successful conversions and assignments; since we are only reading a single item, we expect a return value of `1` on success.  This will loop until EOF or `fscanf` sees a non-whitespace, non-decimal-digit character.

You can have your program read from either a file or standard input with an optional command line parameter:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  FILE *fp = stdin; // default to standard input
  if ( argc > 1 )
  {
    if ( !(fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" )) )
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "Could not open %s\n", argv[1] );
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  }

  while ( fscanf( fp, "%ld", &inputInteger ) == 1 )
  {
    // convert and display integer
  }

  if ( fp != stdin )
    fclose( fp );
}
```